# How to add an icon to a keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, input-source, ukelele

I am using ukelele to create some custom keyboard layouts.

I have created a `.icns` file which contains an image I would like to represent this keyboard layout.

How do I get my macOS Sierra MB Pro to associate this keyboard layout with this icon file? I cannot find an option in ukelele, if there is even one.

Comment: Seriously wtf? Is there a bot/person who just goes around and downvotes on every single one of my questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if ukelele itself implements a way to do this, but the solution turned out to be trivial.

Locate your `.bundle` file which is being used. Mine was at `/Library/Keyboard Layouts/#British.bundle`.

With a terminal, `cd` into the Contents and then Resources subdirectories of the bundle. Now the command `open .` should open finder at this location.

Have fun replacing the `.icns` file within.

Answer (score 0):

You just give the .icns file the same name you gave your .keylayout file and locate them in the same direcory.